# Ansbile Runner callback for stdout specified: awx_display Error

Tags: python, ansible, pyinstaller, ansible-runner

I am developing an agent includes ansible-runner, while I am running any playbook it is normal.

However **when I compile it using pyinstaller**, I am getting below error while executing playbook.

```
ansible_runner.run(playbook="win_restart_service.json")
```

***ERROR! Invalid callback for stdout specified: awx_display***

Comment: please create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller can't automatically resolve all your dependencies in a complex project.
I solved this problem with one additional option to pyinstaller:

```
 --add-data $(VENV)/lib/python$(PYV)/site-packages/ansible_runner:ansible_runner
```

VENV is the path to your virtual inventory, PYV is your python version.